# React Native MapView Crashes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, google-maps, github

My React Native MapView crashes when I build android apk file, however it is smoothly running on simulator.

below is my map view code: DeliveryScreen.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useMemo } from 'react';
import { View, Text, SafeAreaView, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import MapView, { Marker, Polyline, PROVIDER_GOOGLE } from 'react-native-maps';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { HomeIcon } from 'react-native-heroicons/solid';
import { selectRestaurant } from '../features/restaurantSlice';
import { resetBasket } from '../features/basketSlice';



const DeliveryScreen = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const restaurant = useSelector(selectRestaurant);
  const [distance, setDistance] = useState('Calculating...');

  const homeLocation = { latitude: 52.50768847543942, longitude: 13.294998226071066 };

  const clearBasketAndReturnHome = () => {
    dispatch(resetBasket());
    navigation.navigate('Home');
  };

  const calculatedDistance = useMemo(() => {

      const earthRadius = 6371;
      const { lat, long } = restaurant;
      const { latitude, longitude } = homeLocation;

      const dLat = (latitude - lat) * (Math.PI / 180);
      const dLon = (longitude - long) * (Math.PI / 180);

      const a =
        Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) +
        Math.cos(lat * (Math.PI / 180)) * Math.cos(latitude * (Math.PI / 180)) * Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.sin(dLon / 2);

      const c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
      return (earthRadius * c).toFixed(2) + ' km';
  }, [restaurant, homeLocation]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setDistance(calculatedDistance);
  }, [calculatedDistance]);

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#00CCBB' }}>
      <MapView
        provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
        
        initialRegion={{
          latitude: restaurant.lat,
          longitude: restaurant.long,
          latitudeDelta: 0.05,
          longitudeDelta: 0.05,
        }}
        style={{ flex: 1, marginTop: -10, zIndex: 0 }}
      >
        <Polyline
          coordinates={[
            { latitude: restaurant.lat, longitude: restaurant.long },
            homeLocation,
          ]}
          strokeColor="#ee5253"
          strokeWidth={6}
        />
        <Marker coordinate={homeLocation} pinColor="#ee5253" />
        <Marker
          coordinate={{ latitude: restaurant.lat, longitude: restaurant.long }}
          title={restaurant.title}
          description={restaurant.short_description}
        />
      </MapView>

      <SafeAreaView style={{ backgroundColor: 'white', flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center', paddingHorizontal: 10, height: 130 }}>
        <View>
          <Text style={{ fontSize: 14, color: 'gray', paddingLeft: 5 }}>Distance to Restaurant</Text>
          <Text style={{ fontSize: 18, fontWeight: 'bold', paddingLeft: 5 }}>{distance}</Text>
        </View>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={clearBasketAndReturnHome} style={{ right: -45, padding: 12, backgroundColor: '#34D399', borderRadius: 999, zIndex: 50 }}>
          <HomeIcon size={20} color='#FFFFFF' />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </SafeAreaView>
    </View>
  );
};

export default React.memo(DeliveryScreen);
```

**Error from Logcat**

```
Failed to send network request CDP event                                              

okhttp3.internal.http2.StreamResetException: stream was reset: CANCEL

at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream$FramingSource.read(Http2Stream.kt:63)

at okhttp3.internal.connection.Exchange$ResponseBodySource.read(Exchange.kt:16)

at okio.x.read(RealBufferedSource.kt:6)

at okio.l.read(ForwardingSource.kt:8)

at abi49_0_0.com.facebook.react.modules.network.ProgressResponseBody$1.read(ProgressResponseBody.java:1)

at okio.x.w0(RealBufferedSource.kt:36)

at okio.v.read(PeekSource.kt:56)

at okio.x.w0(RealBufferedSource.kt:36)

at okhttp3.Response.peekBody(Response.kt:19)

at abi49_0_0.expo.modules.kotlin.devtools.ExpoRequestCdpInterceptor.didReceiveResponse(ExpoRequestCdpInterceptor.kt:62)

at abi49_0_0.expo.modules.kotlin.devtools.ExpoNetworkInspectOkHttpNetworkInterceptor.intercept(ExpoNetworkInspectOkHttpInterceptors.kt:82)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

at host.exp.exponent.b.g(RNObject.kt:30)

at host.exp.exponent.b.h(RNObject.kt:19)

at as.d0.f(KernelNetworkInterceptor.kt:19)

at as.d0.b(KernelNetworkInterceptor.kt:1)

at as.c0.intercept(R8$$SyntheticClass:1)

at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:167)

at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.kt:33)

at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:167)

at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.kt:192)

at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:167)

at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.kt:171)

at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:167)

at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.kt:35)

at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:167)

at abi49_0_0.expo.modules.kotlin.devtools.ExpoNetworkInspectOkHttpAppInterceptor.intercept(ExpoNetworkInspectOkHttpInterceptors.kt:29)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

at host.exp.exponent.b.g(RNObject.kt:30)

at host.exp.exponent.b.h(RNObject.kt:19)

at as.d0.e(KernelNetworkInterceptor.kt:19)

at as.d0.a(KernelNetworkInterceptor.kt:1)

at as.b0.intercept(R8$$SyntheticClass:1)

at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:167)

at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain$okhttp(RealCall.kt:118)

at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall$AsyncCall.run(RealCall.kt:52)

at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)

at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:644)

at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
```

The code runs smoothly on simulator however when im building an APK file then when it reaches the map, the app crashes and quit.

Please any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Any other error you see on logcat? I can't see anything related to the Maps SDK in the stack trace.

Comment: @Yrll i see no other errors, however the error was due to map package issue, it seemed different versions clashed

Comment: You could try filing an issue in the react-native-maps library repo if you think its an issue on their end.